# Formal verification with Chisel

Tags: hdl, chisel, formal-verification

Is it possible to do formal verification with Chisel3 HDL language?
If yes, is there an open-source software to do that ?
I know that we can do verilog formal verification with Yosys, but with chisel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formal verification is now integrated under [chiseltest](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest) official test library.

Answer (score 2):

SpaceCowboy asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800826/chisel-firrtl-verilog-backend-proof-of-work). And jkoening responded it: not now but maybe it will be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use Yosys-smtbmc with some little hacks described [here](http://www.fabienm.eu/flf/prove-chisel-design-with-yosys-smtbmc/) to «inject» formal properties in Verilog generated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chisel package named [chisel-formal](https://github.com/tdb-alcorn/chisel-formal) now.

```
import chisel3.formal._
```

This extends Module with trait named Formal.

```
class MyModule extends Module with Formal {
//...
      past(io.Mwrite, 1) (pMwrite => {
        when(io.Mwrite === true.B) {
          assert(pMwrite === false.B)
        }
      })
      cover(countreg === 10.U)
//...
}
```

That allow to use assert(), assume(), cover(), past(), ... functions.

Full howto is given on [github repository](https://github.com/tdb-alcorn/chisel-formal).